# jQuery div removeClass() / addClass()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a particular div element with "testDiv" class;

```
<div class="testDiv">Content</div>
```

Now using jQuery I want to remove the testDiv class and add a different class;

```
jQuery('div').removeClass('testDiv');
```

Now how can I add a class to this particular div that got its class remove, i fear that if I do `jQuery('div').addClass('newClass');` it will add a class to all the other divs present in the page.

Comment: Why not just `jQuery('.testDiv').toggleClass('testDiv newClass');`?

Comment: i dont want to completely eliminate the old class

Comment: @Bojangles There's no point using `toggleClass()` unless you intend to toggle the classes again, which won't work with your example :p

Answer (score 9, accepted):

how about:

```
jQuery('div.testDiv').addClass('newClass').removeClass('testDiv');
```

Comment: Another approach would be to put an id on the div and then do `$('#yourdivid').addClass('addclass').removeClass(removeClass);`

Comment: @Robert that would be ideal, but I intend to have the same container wrapping many elements, hence, I can only use class

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery('div.testDiv').toggleClass("testDiv newClass")
```

Comment: straight forward : addClass / removeClass = toggleClass